# STM32: How to configure timer to trigger interrupt in every increments in quadrature encoder mode?

Tags: timer, stm32, interrupt, encoder

I have a rotary encoder with STM32F4 and configured TIM4 in "Encoder Mode  TI1 and TI2". I want to have an interrupt every time the value of timer is incremented or decremented.

The counting works but I only can configure an interrupt on every update event, not every changes in TIM4->cnt. How can I do this?

In other words: My MCU+Encoder in quadrature mode could count from 0 to 99 in one revolution. I want to have 100 interrupts in the revolution but if I set TIM4->PSC=0 and TIM4->ARR=1, results 50 UPDATE_EVENTs, so I should set ARR=0 but it does not work. How can I sole that?

Comment: I am interested for the same thing for G0 series. So far I can only think of using io level change interrupts assuming that by the time of the interrupt call the timer counter would be updated by HW encoder. I would however prefer something tied to change of actual timer counter. Using CC registers is ugly to check for race conditions,  so that it not ideal either.

Answer (score 0):

To get 100 interrupts per revolution keep PSC=0, ARR=1, setup the two timer channels in output compare mode with compare values 0 and 1 and interrupts on both channels.

Or even use ARR=3 and setup all four channels, with compare values of 0,1,2 and 3. This will allow to detect the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the whole point of using the quadrature encoder mode is counting the pulses while *avoiding* interrupts. You can simply poll the counter register periodically to determine speed and position.

Getting interrupts on every encoder pulse is extremely inefficient, especially with high resolution encoders. Yours seems to be a low resolution one. If you still think you need them for some reason, you can connect A & B into external interrupts and implement the counting logic manually. In this case, you don't need quadrature encoder mode.

Answer (score -2):

```
void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
  {
    n_pulses =__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim2)//HAL_TIM_Encoder_GetState(htim);
  }
```

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.